# Function resolution order in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm not sure if MRO is the correct term for this but let's take the following example:

```
summary_df = df.groupby(['provider', 'master_id']).agg(
    content_type_id     =('content_type_id', 'sum')
)
```

The `sum` will run when it is listed in strings. Yet it will also return if it's not in a string, for example:

```
summary_df = df.groupby(['provider', 'master_id']).agg(
    content_type_id     =('content_type_id', sum)
)
```

What functions may I pass here? Locally defined functions? Globally defined functions? etc. What is the 'lookup order' for the function?

Comment: might be out of my depth here, but have you had a look at the source code for [.agg](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.1.3/pandas/core/frame.py#L7347-L7378) ? also `.sum` works for strings outside of `.agg` however if you passed `mean` you would get an attribute error.

Comment: From the docs: Function to use for aggregating the data. If a function, must either work when passed a DataFrame or when passed to DataFrame.apply and same goes for if the input is a Series